# Convert pdf to image in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I have followed this other topic to get a image from pdf

[How to convert a pdf to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292417/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image-in-android-using-pdfbox-getting-error-to-import-ja)

I want to use this image as a pdf preview, this is de code that I have

```
private Bitmap showPage(int page, float zoom) throws Exception {
    Bitmap b=null;
    try {

        mPdfPage = mPdfFile.getPage(page, true);
        float wi = mPdfPage.getWidth();
        float hei = mPdfPage.getHeight();


        RectF clip = null;

        Bitmap bi = mPdfPage.getImage((int)(wi*zoom), (int)(hei*zoom), clip, true, true);
        b=bi;

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Firstpdf.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        Log.e("amit","Go to page bitmap______SAVE");

    } catch (Throwable e) {

    }

    return b;
}
```

but in this line

```
Bitmap bi = mPdfPage.getImage((int)(wi*zoom), (int)(hei*zoom), clip, true, true);
```

I get this error

```
The method getImage(int, int, Rectangle2D, ImageObserver) in the type PDFPage is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, RectF, boolean, boolean)
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The method `getImage` requires 4 parameters but you have passed 5. Check the documentation and provide correct parameters.

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java) he use with 3 parameters, but I can't, i'm using PDFRenderer.jar, maybe it is incorrect library

Comment: In [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android-Open-Source-App/Media/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/com/sun/pdfview/PDFPage.java.htm) there is a method impletation with 3 parameters and It returns a Bitmap (getImage(int width, int height, RectF clip)), but I can't acces, I only can to a method with 4 parameters and return a Image